# Can't get SQL query result, when using * (not column names)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I can only get results from a SQL query execution when I use `select columnname from tablename`, but not when I use `select * from tablename`

```
public static void connectAndExecute(String host, String uName, String uPass, String sqlQuery) {
    try { 
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        String[] conData = null;
        Statement stmt = null;      

        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            /*this is the place of my problem*/
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from getting the results?  What is the actual problem?

Comment: Do you see some exception? In this case please post the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ResultSet.class` methods to get the desired result. You can give the column names or column index.

`getInt(int columnIndex)`

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as an int in the Java programming language.

`getString(int columnIndex)`

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.

Here is how you can implement it:

```
while(rs.next()){ 
//Retrieve by column index 
int id = rs.getInt(1); //assume id is at 1st index
int age = rs.getInt(4); //assume age is at 4th index
String first = rs.getString(2); // assume first name is at 2nd index
String last = rs.getString(3); // assume last name is at 3rd index
//Display values 
System.out.print("ID: " + id); System.out.print(", Age: " + age); System.out.print(", First: " + first); System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
System.out.println(" End of one row"); 
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was really helpfull. it also shows me how stupid my question was

Comment: Happy coding! You can mark it as right answer if it was really helpful.

Comment: No problem bro.. every1 has to start somewhere.